# Equivalence of a lim sup of functions with a lim inf of sets.

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

$\{\omega\in\Omega : \limsup_{n\to\infty}\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)\rvert=0\}$ =$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\{{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)\rvert\lt \epsilon\}}\forall\epsilon>0$.

How do we turn the LHS which is a lim sup on functions to the RHS which is a lim inf on sets.

Comment: You forgot a complement somewhere....

Comment: @user10354138 fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remember $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \lvert x_n-x\rvert=0$ for $x_n,x\in\mathbb{R}$ means for all $\epsilon>0$, $\lvert x_n-x\rvert<\epsilon$ eventually.

So
\begin{align*}
&\{\omega\in\Omega:\limsup_{n\to\infty}\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)\rvert=0\}\\
&=\{\omega\in\Omega:(\forall\epsilon>0)(\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)\rvert<\epsilon\text{ eventually})\}\\
&=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)\rvert<\epsilon\text{ eventually}\}\\
&=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)\rvert<\epsilon\}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is the set then equal to $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\bigcap_{k\ge n}\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)\rvert<\epsilon\}$

Comment: yes, or equivalently, since $\mathbb{R}$ is Archimedean, $\bigcap_{m>0}\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcap_{k\geq n}\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)<\frac1m\}$.

Comment: Could you have a look at my question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271679/almost-sure-convergence-characterisations